# Android: how to functional test that a broadcast receiver has been registered/unregistered in onResume/onPause methods

Tags: android, testing

I am trying to test that the correct **BroadcastReceiver** has been registered in the **onResume()** method of my **Activity** and unregistered in the **onPause()** method, shown below.

```
/* register the broadcast receiver with the intent values to be matched */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    this.registerReceiver(this.activityBroadcastReceiver,
            this.activityIntentFilter);
}

/* unregister the broadcast receiver */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(this.activityBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the list of registered **BroadcastReceiver**'s from an Activity ?

P.S. I know that I can use **ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.callActivityOnPause(myActivity)** to trigger **onPause()**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no official API to do that. What you could do is using a `try` statement to test it, so something like:

```
try { register_your_receiver(); }
catch(IllegalArgumentException e) { hey_something_went_wrong(); }
```

Comment: hmm I don't see anything in registerReceiver docs saying that it will throw an exception if the receiver already exists.

Comment: Now that you tell, I tried to find it in the official documentation and didn't find it neither, but I remember to have this battle a time ago, so I had a look where did I find that info and this is it, see the second message: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/3dOZXz53NP0

I think that might help you

Comment: Thanks NKN. Unfortunately I can't rely on that in production code because it's not a documented (guaranteed) behaviour.

Comment: I understand, hope someone helps you with that!